# When i go from view back to tab bar controller, the tab bar doesnt show

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

I'm going from a tab bar controller view to another view thats not part of the tab bar controller. When, I  try and go back from the view to the tab bar controller view, by pressing the back button, the tab bar doesn't show. The code for the button is under back_golf. The view isn't in a navigational controller

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class Golf: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var tableview_golf: UITableView!

var array = [String]()
var ref : DatabaseReference!
var handle: DatabaseHandle!

@IBAction func back_golf(_ sender: Any) {


let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let navigationController = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as! 
UINavigationController

 navigationController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  //self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
 //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "seque_golf", sender: nil)
 //hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
ref = Database.database().reference()
handle = ref?.child("Girls_golf").observe(.childAdded, with: { 
(snapshot) in
    if let item = snapshot.value as? String {
        self.array.append(item)
        self.tableview_golf.reloadData()
    }

})


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
Int) -> Int {
return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableview_golf.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"golf_cell")! as UITableViewCell
cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
return cell
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

[image: Here's a picture that might help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have poped over the ViewControllers (in this example "Golf"). If this is true, this should be worked for:

```
@IBAction func back_golf(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```